# Adding Attributes to XML file Linq C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I wanna add a Test (common) attribute to all my XML files. So that I could use it as a common attribute when I wanna test them.

I tried CreateAttribute but Linq dosen't recognize it

I tried "xElement.Add(new XAttribute("Test", value));" but it also didn't work 
Any Suggestions?

Thanks

Here for example is a code

```
    public void updateXmlFile(string strFileName)
    {
        XDocument oXDoc = XDocument.Load(strFileName);
        XElement oDcElement = oXDoc.Root.FirstNode as XElement;

        //Generate a Unique String to replace the original attribute value
        string newValue = GetUniqueKey();

        //oDcElement.Add(new XAttribute("Test", newValue)); /*NullReferenceException*/

        oDcElement.Attribute("Remark").Value = newValue; //This changes only the Remark Attribute
        oXDoc.Save(strFileName);                         //which isn't available in all XMLs

    }
```

I wanna add an additional, common value to the XMLs I pass through this method and give it a random value

My goal is to be able to make changes on an XML then compare it against the original copy in another folder

Comment: You seem to be on the right lines, please can you paste the full source?

Answer (score 8):

Use SetAttribute:

```
oDcElement.SetAttributeValue("Test", newValue);
```

Comment: I figured I can't do it since I'm retrieving Data from the DB and if I wanna add an attribute I have to add an extra coloumn to the DB.

Comment: Your original question says nothing about a DB.  It's just adding a new attribute to a node of an XML file loaded from the filesystem.  I don't understand what your comment means.