# ideas to modify attributes of different XML files c#

Tags: c#, xml

here is my scenario,

1. I copy XML Files from the Original Directory to the Target Directory
2. I modify the file's attributes in the Original Directory
3. I compare the modified file's attribute(from the Original Directory) with the copied file's attribute (in the Target Directory) They shouldn't be the same of course

My problem is that NOT all XML Files have the same attributes.

I tried adding a common attribute and modify it but the files are retrieved from a DB and each attribute represents a coloumn there and I can't modify the DB

I'm thinking of looping through the attributes, till I reach the first "non-fixed" attribute and modify it. Is that possible? if so how? and if there is other solutions I'll appreciate it even more :)

Here is an example of part of my xmls

```
<CtApproachTypes 
DataclassId="1992A9CE-B048-4676-BFD4-FD81F1A65401" 
EntityId="1992A9CE-B048-4676-BFD4-FD81F1A65401" 
Name="PAR" 
Remark="No Remarks"/>
</CT_ApproachTypes>

<MiMissions 
DataclassId="C196A66B-4FA1-461C-9EEF-95A4F2085051" 
EntityId="C196A66B-4FA1-461C-9EEF-95A4F2085051" 
MissionName="Standard"
isib="1" 
</MiMissions>

<StSituations 
DataclassId="679FAC3C-C9EF-41FD-9A13-957915605F01" 
EntityId="679FAC3C-C9EF-41FD-9A13-957915605F01" 
SitName="Standard" 
Status="C" 
Template="1">
</StSituations>
```

I wanna skip the first two attributes and modify the first attribute after them.

Note: I checked the XML Files and all of them seem to have an attribute with "-name" in them. I was thinking of using "like" to query.. but a more solid solution would be to modify the first attribute after the first 2.

Thanks

Comment: To make the question clearer you may add some examples of where you want your attributes to land in the different file.

Comment: I don't want them to land anywhere. I just need to change one attribute in the original XML File and then compare it with the XML File copied in another directory

Comment: This sounds like the other question you already asked (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565038/adding-attributes-to-xml-file-linq-c).  And step 1 says you're copying from a directory but then you said the files are retrieved from a DB.  Could you clarify your question as yo exactly what you need help with (not the whole process of what you ARE doing, just the spot you need help on).

Comment: The Data is retrieved from the DB. Stored into an XML File with Attributes representing the Columns of the DB. These XML Files are stored in a Directory..etc

Comment: Can't anyone help me with that? No ideas? or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If what you're trying to do is update attributes of XML this could be one way:

```
XElement elem = XElement.Load("xmlFilePath");
System.Xml.XPath.Extensions.XPathSelectElement(elem, "xpath").SetAttributeValue("attributeName", "newValue");
```

where xmlFilePath is the path to the XML you're changing, xpath is the path to the element of the xml and attributeName is the name of the nodes attribute you're altering...
Ofcourse, you have to add a custom node with attribute to every xml you're using.

**EDIT:**
Since you said you can't modify the XML files in both locations, than all you're left with is to compare the `FileInfo` properties of the files themselves.

And if the `FileInfo` properties are not what you need, then there's no other solution but to create a tracking db or a file, which will contain attribute values for your Original and Target directory, by which you can compare and do appropriate action.

For example, if your Original and Target maps 1 on 1, than you could have a simple table structure like this 'TableName, OriginalValue, TargetValue'. Where you'd keep this 'tracking' data (db, xml file, other...) depends on the number of entries, and your current architecture...

**EDIT2:**
If you wan't to append to the first attribute found you can use this:

```
    XElement elem = XElement.Load("myfilepath.xml");
    elem.FirstAttribute.SetValue(elem.FirstAttribute.Value + "|myothervalue");
```

Comment: I can't add a custom node that's the problem. The XMLs are generated from DB Coloumns representing their attributes. And I can't modify the DB. What I need is a way to modify the XML Files knowing that not all XML Files have a common Attribute.

Comment: You can add attribute at root element because the root always exists and it's not related to tables (if that's not the case, please post a simple xml example of your file).
If the attribute doesn't exist the SetAttributeValue will create it for you - just make sure it's some unique name just in case.

Comment: I used the "SetAttributeValue" and added a new attribute named "Sabassi" but it still gave me the NullReferenceException.. :S

Comment: Okay so I just realized that i can't add a new attribute. Since I'm gonna compare the XML file with the other (copied) which won't have the newly added attribute (that's why I've been getting the NullException every time I try to compare the 2 xml files). So What I need to do now is simply modify an already existing attribute in the original xml so that it would be valid for comparison when I compare it with the copied file. But then we return to the same problem, that not all XMLs have a common attribute... Anyway of solving this?

Comment: No it has to be through Attributes Comparison, not the whole XML. I'm looking into FirstOrDefault() function now but I keep reaching a dead end. It is somehow what I need. That is to loop through the Attributes of the XML file, find the first attribute that accepts modifying (not with a fixed value) then modify it. And I can then apply this loop on the copied xml files and will return the same attribute. Can you help me with this in any possible way?

Comment: that's really helpful. Sort of what I wanted. It worked (gave me no errors) but it didn't change the value either since the first attribute is DataClassId (fixed) the 2nd is also fixed (EntityId). But what I need now is to write a condition that would skip these and jump right to the 3rd attribute. If you could also tell me of a way to retrieve the change attribute for testing purposes I would be thankful